# How to change inline code appearance with custom css in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I can  change code appearance with custom css for code chunks (font family Arial in my example)

```
code.r{ /* Code block */
     font-family: arial;
}
```

How can I do this for inline  `code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unevaluated inline code is contained inside a `code` element with no class:

```
`round(pi, 3)`
```

leads to

```
<code>round(pi, 3)</code>
```

Therefore using the CSS selector `code {}` is sufficient.