# Can I apply styling to inline code in an R Notebook?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook, inline-code

When you use inline code in an R Markdown document, the code is evaluated and the output is incorporated into the text. For example,

```
The sum of 2 and 2 is `r 2+2`.
```

This will generate the following text in the `.nb.html` file:

> The sum of 2 and 2 is 4.

That text is not styled or tagged in any way in the HTML output, so there is no way to apply CSS.

But I'd like to be able to see in the HTML document if text appears "as is" or if it was processed through inline code. In other words, I want to know see a difference in the appearance of the number 4 if I write

```
The sum of 2 and 2 is `r 2+2`.
```

versus

```
The sum of 2 and 2 is 4.
```

Is there any way to do this?

(The use case here is that I have students who are supposed to use inline code in their assignments, but if I'm looking at the `.nb.html` file and not the `.Rmd` file, I can't tell if they just manually typed in an answer without using code to generate it.)

**EDIT: My original question said R Markdown, and there is a good solution to that question below. However, I need this to work in an R Notebook, and it seems that `knit_hooks$set` is ignored when creating the HTML file.**

Comment: Not an answer but am interested in one myself: Could this be a bug/regression? It seems that this was [possible in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385764/how-to-change-inline-code-appearance-with-custom-css-in-rmarkdown). A workaround using a custom `<span>` class inside `sprintf` [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727217/rmarkdown-change-inline-code-color) but a bit awkward. Perhaps this is worth a RMarkdown [GH issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues).

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using `knitr::knit_hooks$set`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Shafayet Khan"
date: "2022-07-31"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

random_class <- paste0("class-", round(runif(1, 200, 2000)))

styleIt <- function(x) {
  paste0("<span class='", random_class, "' style=\"color: red;\">", x,"</span>")
}

knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = styleIt)
```

## R Markdown

### inline code

The sum of 2 and 2 is `r 2+2`

### not inline code

The sum of 2 and 2 is 4.

### Manually styled

The sum of 2 and 2 is <span style="color: red;">4</span>
````

When rendered, it looks like

[image: inline_colored_code]

Now note that the students always can use the `span` tag to get the same color as the inline code, so to make a difference, I have used a randomly generated class and used that for inline code, so when you have the HTML file, `span` tag for an inline code should have a randomly generated class name like `class-672` while manually typed and colored code will unlikely have that same class name. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm...so this works for `html_document` but not for `html_notebook`. (Unfortunately, I need to use R Notebooks. That wasn't clear from my question, though, so that's my fault.) I can't figure out why that would be, except that for `html_notebook` you don't explicitly "knit" the file.

Comment: I've edited the question to make this clear. Thanks @shafee for your excellent response to the question in its original form.

Comment: @SeanRaleigh, sorry, I am a bit confused with this *"for `html_notebook` you don't explicitly "knit" the file."* Because if I am understanding it correctly, for R notebook you can do **knit to HTML**, right?

Comment: You can knit to HTML but that just creates a new output line in the YAML header for `html_document` and processes the file that way. The workflow for my beginning students is way easier if I use exclusively `html_notebook`.